# Convert JavaScript`s Number to Scala's Double

Tags: scala.js

How to convert an instance of untyped `js.Dynamic`, which I know is a JavaScript `number`, to a Scala Double type?

Background: I have a js library that doesn't have a Scala.js wrapper around it (yet). It sends certain events, and I want to use those events' data in Scala code, where I need proper typing.

What I've done so far is the following: first js `number` to Scala's `String`, and the `String` to `Double`.

```
map.addListener("click", {(e: js.Dynamic) => {
      val c = map.pixelToGeo(e.displayX, e.displayY)
      GenerateSampleData.mapClickCoord() = 
        Coordinate(
          String.valueOf(c.latitude).toDouble,
          String.valueOf(c.longitude).toDouble)
    }})
```

It works, but I think it looks ugly, and there must be a better way. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@sjrd will correct me if I'm wrong, but I believe that Scala's Double *is* a JS Number under the hood. So if you're confident that `c.latitude` is a Number, I believe you can simply say:

```
c.latitude.asInstanceOf[Double]
```

Comment: You're right. It works, and noticeably faster than my original version. With my approach, I was really able to see delays between clicks on the map and values changing with my naked eye. Not with this approach. I'll postpone accepting this answer, though, maybe other ideas will come up.